# Danish Social Security Number validation

Tags: php, validation

Anyone has a script or know where I can find one to validate Danish Social Security Numbers in PHP?

I need to validate the format, the checksum and the dates need to be valid numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number_(Denmark)) Danish SSNs are a string of 10-digit numbers with a hyphen between digits 6 and 7. With that in mind, you can perform quick validation using a regular expression such as `"/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}/"` – any six digits then a hyphen then then any four digits.

Here's an example in code:

```
<?php
    $goodSSN = "220177-1234";
    $badSSN = "220A77-1234";

    $regex = "/[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}/";

    if (preg_match($regex, $goodSSN)) {
        echo "Good: You should see this message because this was a good SSN.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Good: You won't see this message.\n";
    }

    if (preg_match($regex, $badSSN)) {
        echo "Bad: You won't see this message.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Bad: You should see this message because this was a bad SSN.\n";
    }
?>
```

If you wanted to validate more precisely, you would need to break up the digits into smaller groups (e.g. days, months, years), then validate each group.

Comment: Thanks! But I also need to validate the checksum etc.

Comment: You can't do that, I'm afraid. From Wikipedia: "However, in 2007 the available sequence numbers under this system for males born on 1 January 1965 ran out, and since October 2007 personal identification numbers do not always validate using the check digit. This had been predicted and announced several years in advance. **Thus, most IT systems are presumed updated to accept numbers that fail the check-digit validation**."

Comment: @user1878980: May I suggest, given the limitation I mentioned, that my answer is as close as you are going to get without a great deal more work? If so, it would be helpful if you could mark my answer as correct so others could benefit.